# I am getting Error: Cycle when running a terraform plan

Tags: terraform

I was getting the following error while running terraform plan:

Error: Cycle: aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.mlops_datapipeline_notebookinstance_main, aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.mlops_datapipeline_notebookinstance_demo, data.aws_iam_policy_document.sagemaker_neptune-access, aws_iam_policy.sagemaker_execution_policy, aws_neptune_cluster.neptune_for_demo, aws_neptune_cluster.neptune_for_main, data.aws_iam_policy_document.neptune-access, aws_iam_policy.neptune_access_policy, aws_iam_role.Neptune_execution_role

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using AWS because your filename contains "ec2", even though you don't show enough code in your question or provide enough details.

The AWS Terraform provider expects `tags` to be a map, not a single string. You have enclosed the entire thing in double quotes, converting it into a string. Try this:

```
tags = merge(var.tags, map({"Name", format("%s-%d", var.name, count.index+1)}))
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. can we change it in .terraform/modules/main.tf file?

Comment: The files in `.terraform/modules` are generated by Terraform when you run `terraform init`. There should not be .tf files in that folder. It is entirely unclear what you are doing with files in the `.terraform` folder.

Comment: I am getting following kind of errors while running terraform plan:

Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/ec2-datapipeline/main.tf line 24, in resource "aws_instance" "this":
│   24:   ebs_block_device       = "${var.ebs_block_device}"
│ 
│ An argument named "ebs_block_device" is not expected here. Did you mean to
│ define a block of type "ebs_block_device"?

Comment: That error is totally unrelated to the question you originally asked. You are trying to pass a single string as an ebs_block_device setting, which is incorrect just as the error message is trying to tell you.